# compartir una propiedad en diferentes funciones dentro de una misma clase en php

Tags: php, wordpress, php5

Hola comunidad tengo este ejemplo de codigo, donde no estoy recibiendo el valor de $algo en la funcion pasarDato, ya que viene null, que esta pasando

```
class NombreClase extend X {

    private $algo;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array($this, 
        'crearTexto') );
    }

    function crearTexto() {
        $propiedad = 'xcosa';
        $this->algo = $propiedad;
        return $this->algo;
    }

    public function pasarDato() {
        $algoMas=$this->algo;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿como estás ejecutando ese código?  Tal como lo has puesto, primero debes ejecutar crearTexto() y luego pasarDato() sobre la misma instancia de objeto de esa clase que hayas creado.  ¿lo haces asi?

Comment: asi es, primero ejecuto crearTexto() y luego pasarDato(), cabe mencionar que crearTexto lo ejecuto en el constructor que internamente tiene parent::__construct();
y la funcion crarTexto() la ejecuto de la siguiente forma add_filter( 'ecommerce_before_form', array($this, 'crearTexto') );

Comment: eso suena a wordpress... ni idea, lo siento... si es wordpress añade lo que has comentado a la pregunta y agrega la etiqueta wordpress también

Comment: afirmo es wordpress y ya agregue lo pasado gracias por las sugerencias

Comment: Wordpress trabaja con PHP como tal, así que no hay ningún misterio al respecto, por tanto, no tienes por qué retroceder @masterguru :) Dicho eso, Alex, me extraña que hayas metido un `add_filter` en el contexto de la clase. ¿Puedes explicarnos qué sentido tiene haber metido eso ahí? Eso sería algo propio del contexto, es decir, donde creas la instancia de la clase y la usas. Meterlo en la clase la ata a Wordpress, capándola. Por otra parte, no entiendo el propósito de `pasarDato` ¿? Asignas una variable llamada `$algoMas`, pero, ¿para qué, si no se ve que hagas nada con `$algoMas` ¿?

Comment: @A.Cedano jeje, bueno, es que soy un anti-WP por así decirlo... me he hartado de el cuando trabajaba en el mundillo del hosting por la cantidad de hackeos que tuve que solucionar y la cantidad de plugins de penosa calidad que usaban mis clientes que sobrecargaban recursos y abrian puertas a nuevas vulnerabilidades.  Fíjate si lo odio que jamás he querido usarlo como usuario, y acabé creando mi propio CMS (mas cutre, menos plugins, pero me ha servido mucho para aprender PHP a pelo).... pero eso no quita que haya tenido que arreglar cosas de WP muchas veces, pues como bien dices, es PHP. :-)

Comment: realmente soy nuevo en php, lo que necesitaba con crearTexto es llamar un dato en especifico cunado se carga la pantalla,  para despues usarlo en el pasarDato, y en cunato a por que use add_filter, realmente es por mi poco o nullo conocimiento de php

Comment: @masterguru, lamentablemente me toco agregar una modificacion, y el producto esta montado en WP, soy desarrollador de angular y react, asi que te imaginaras como estoy batallando,  mas que es la primera ves que toco PHP

Comment: @AlexNavedo je, te entiendo, si fuera al reves yo también estaría perdido.  Suerte!  Pista: Busca en el código fuente de WP que hace la función add_filter y mira como la usan los plugins para entender mejor como funciona WP.  Como bien dice A.Cedano, no deberías usar un add_filter dentro de una clase, sino más bien cuando la clase este hecha lo ejecutas fuera si realmente lo necesitas implementar (pero repito, no se suficiente WP para ayudarte igualmente, ni ganas tengo de verlo ni aprenderlo, sorry, je)

Comment: @masterguru te doy toda la razón, WP es un bodrio, pero cuando empiezas y quieres montar una página web sin conocer PHP, te parece mágico (fue mi caso), abrí una web sin tener ni idea de PHP, luego, cuando te hackean, te ves obligado a aprender PHP. Todavía tengo mi página en WP, pero he desarrollado todo en PHP puro. No todo es  malo en WP, por ejemplo los `shortcode` que es lo único que uso, me permiten enlazar el frontend con mi propio código PHP en backend. Bueno, hace unos meses leí un poco sobre Symfony y me encantó, y ahora me estoy metiendo en él para abandonar WP pronto.

Comment: Alex, te aconsejo que saques el `add_filter` de ahí, y que lo uses en el contexto en que creas la instancia de la clase. Por otra parte, conviene que clarifiques el propósito de tu clase, pues, como te comenté más arriba, el método `pasarDato()` tal y como lo tienes ahora, no sirve de nada. Esto no va siquiera de WP o no WP, sino de **lógica**. Además, piensa tus clases como una entidad, que programas para resolver o representar algo. Digo esto porque si mañana quieres migrar a otro lado, cosa no muy rara, tu clase no te servirá, si metes en ella código propio de WP.

Comment: @A.Cedano yo en mis proyectos uso mi propio framework (que no es más que una ampliación de mi CMS original), el cual no comparto el código con nadie, y que también está hecho a pelo.  Nunca quise ver como eran los otros frameworks ni los otros CMS para no tener influencias o dependencias directas de ninguno.  De tal modo que creo que nadie del mundo mundial podría entenderlo, pues está hecho unos zorros con mezcla de código de cuando empezaba a programar con código de ahora que ya dominio un poco más, jeje. Por eso nunca lo he compartido ni lo haré (por verguenza, jeje). Pero me funciona :-D

Comment: @A.Cedano, disculpa es que es solo parte del codigo, realmente pasarDato() se ejecuta al darclick a un boton de pago y el dato se va no solo a php si no tambien a Js, es codigo bastante coplejo de seguridad en pagos, entonces es importante que la primera funciona se ejecute al cargar la pantalla de pago que es donde pertenece esa clase, en cuanto al add filter, si conocen otro metodo para llamar esa funcion al cargar la ventana de pago les agradeceria me brinden su guia, ya que si uso directo la funcion dentro del contructor la llama como 4 veces

Comment: @masterguru lo que me ha atado a WP hasta ahora ha sido la parte visual de mi web (en el pasado compré el framework Thesis, que traía además varios Temas basados en Thesis). Ya con el tiempo aprendí algunas cosas sobre `.css` y`.js` y cuando vi la App de demostración de Symfony me gustó, porque te permite crear un sitio responsivo sin demasiadas complicaciones. Otra cosa que me gusta es la facilidad con que puedes desplegar tu app, guardando además una copia en un repositorio de código o migrar a entornos como Google Cloud para alojar tu sitio. Hice una prueba y es apasionante :)

Comment: Alex, por eso insisto en que saques el `add_filter` de ahí, en un entorno WP ese código iría en el archivo `functions.php` u otro, si tuvieras frameworks como Thesis o Genesis ... Es desde ese entorno que debes conectar tu WP con tu propio código (en este caso la clase que nos muestras en la pregunta). No puedo ayudarte con más propiedad, porque falta contexto en la pregunta. Es desde `functions.php` que llamas a todos los archivos externos, sea `.js`, sea `.css`, y también desde ahí puedes pasar a usar tus propias clases y tu propio código en `.php` puro.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo malo del código abierto es que es justamente eso, abierto, por lo tanto cualquiera puede terminar encontrando una vulnerabilidad en el para explotarlo y entonces empiezan los hackeos masivos.  Seguramente muchos frameworks ya no son tan vulnerables como antes, pero con solo pensar que lo pudieran ser los evito todos, y uso tan solo el mio, el cual, al no ser abierto, y estar solo puesto en unas 20 webs, no saben por donde atacar por muchos ataques de fuerza bruta o de búsqueda de scripts vulnerables típicos que hagan.

Comment: @A.Cedano y eso lo hago así debido a lo que decia antes... muchos años llevando servidores de hosting con hackeos constantes con todo tipo de tiendas, cms y frameworks abiertos... desde WP, pasando por joomlas, magentos, prestashops, etc... todos vulnerables, la mayoria gracias a plugins chungos, pero algunos tambien por su propio código base no actualizado... y eso me ha hecho desconfiar de todos :-)

Comment: @masterguru te entiendo, pero el repositorio puede ser privado dando acceso sólo a la plataforma en que quieres desplegar la App y en cuanto Symfony, según he leído, es lo más seguro que hay. Incluso el mismo WP para mi es seguro, si evitas los plugin, en el pasado tuve un hackeo y fue debido a un plugin, desde que dejé de usar plugin, no tuve problemas. Otro riesgo son los hosting compartidos, pero llevo años con ese tipo de alojamiento y ningún problema desde que dejé de usar los plugin.